# ALTER DATABASE MODIFY FILEGROUP [myfilegroup] AUTOGROW_ALL_FILES

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I would like to change all file groups in my database to AutoGrow_all_Files, but only if it is currently AutoGrow_Single_File, like this:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydatabase MODIFY FILEGROUP [myfilegroup] AUTOGROW_ALL_FILES
```

How can I check this database property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.filegroups` contains a column `is_autogrow_all_files` that indicates if the setting is already turned on for the filegroup in question.

This should show a list of alter database statements you can run:

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC 
FOR
SELECT '
select ''ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + ' MODIFY FILEGROUP '' + QUOTENAME(ds.name) + '' AUTOGROW_ALL_FILES;''
from ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.sys.data_spaces ds
    INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.sys.filegroups fg ON ds.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id
WHERE fg.is_autogrow_all_files = 0;
'
FROM sys.databases d;
OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cmd;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT (@cmd);
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cmd;
END
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

The code will display a set of statements you can run for each database on the instance, to modify each file group.

And example of the statement generated is:

```
select 'ALTER DATABASE [msdb] MODIFY FILEGROUP ' + QUOTENAME(ds.name) + ' AUTOGROW_ALL_FILES;'
from [msdb].sys.data_spaces ds
    INNER JOIN [msdb].sys.filegroups fg ON ds.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id
WHERE fg.is_autogrow_all_files = 0;
```

Comment: thank you for giving me just what I needed. I have had do change a few things; your code works on master, model, and in-memory filegroups. I've posted my edition, in case you want to see how I did.

Comment: I'm glad to help, @Henrik.

Answer (score 4):

Complementing to both Max and Kenneth's answers ..

I would suggest you to apply [SQL Server 2016 CU1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3164674) as there is a [known bug with `AUTOGROW_ALL_FILES` property](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3163924) -

> The property isn't preserved after the database or the server restarts. The sys.filegroups viewstill shows that the corresponding column for the property (is_autogrow_all_files and is_read_only) is set to 1. However, it's not actually effective.

Also, its important to note that in [SQL Server 2016 you dont need TF 1117](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/sql-server-2016-changes-in-default-behavior-for-autogrow-and-allocations-for-tempdb-and-user-databases/) since `is_autogrow_all_files` is equivalent of TF1117

Comment: thank you for pointing this out, but yes, we are running CU1.

Answer (score 3):

SSMS 17.8 introduced UI support for this feature. From [SSMS 17.8 is now available](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2018/06/21/ssms-17-8-is-now-available/):

> In this release of SQL Server Management Studio, we have introduced UI and scripting support for the **AUTOGROW_ALL_FILES** database filegroup property.
>
> This property was introduced in SQL Server 2016 to replace trace flag 1117, but it was only settable via T-SQL script.  Now you can set the property via a checkbox in the Database Properties -> Filegroups page

[image]
<sup>Image source: https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/uploads/prod/2018/06/image-1-sql-server.png</sup>

> You can also use the “Script” button to script out the change:
>
> ```
> USE [AdventureWorks2016_EXT] 
>
> GO
>
> declare @autogrow bit 
>
> SELECT @autogrow=convert(bit, is_autogrow_all_files) 
>   FROM sys.filegroups WHERE name=N'PRIMARY' 
>
> if(@autogrow=0) 
>
> ALTER DATABASE [AdventureWorks2016_EXT] 
>   MODIFY FILEGROUP [PRIMARY] AUTOGROW_ALL_FILES 
>
> GO
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The setting is per filegroup.  You can look in sys.filegroups.

```
SELECT is_autogrow_all_files, * FROM sys.filegroups
```

`sys.filegroups` bol: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187782.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to the problem of getting even file growth on all files in the database:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 
DECLARE @db_name sysname, @sql NVARCHAR(max)='', @Mainsql NVARCHAR(max)='', @rowCount int

SELECT @Mainsql = @@VERSION
--SELECT @Mainsql 
--Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6529.0 (X64)   Mar 19 2015 13:19:13   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor) 
--Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)   Oct 28 2016 18:17:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) 

IF @Mainsql NOT LIKE '%SQL Server 2016%' BEGIN
    SELECT 'This script does not work on servers prior to SQL Server 2016. Please check before continuing'
    SELECT @Mainsql
END

Begin TRY
    DROP TABLE #h
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
CREATE TABLE #h (i INT IDENTITY(1,1), sqltxt NVARCHAR(max))
DELETE FROM #h

DECLARE dbcursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR 
    SELECT name FROM sys.databases 
    WHERE is_read_only=0 AND state_desc='ONLINE' 
    AND source_database_id is NULL AND name NOT IN ('master', 'model', 'msdb')
    ORDER BY name

OPEN dbcursor

FETCH NEXT FROM dbcursor INTO @db_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    RAISERROR (' %s' , 10, 1, @db_name) WITH NOWAIT
    SET @rowCount=0
    SELECT @Mainsql =''
    SELECT @Mainsql += '
    SELECT @rowCount=count(*)
    FROM [' + @db_name + '].sys.filegroups F 
    WHERE type <> ''FD''  /* no FILESTREAM_DATA_FILEGROUP */
    AND type <> ''FX'' /* no MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA_FILEGROUP */
    AND is_autogrow_all_files=0
    '
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC sys.sp_executesql @Mainsql, N'@rowCount int output', @rowCount OUTPUT
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        RAISERROR ('Unable to access %s' , 10, 1, @db_name) WITH NOWAIT
        RAISERROR ('SQL: %s' , 10, 1, @Mainsql) WITH NOWAIT
    END CATCH

    --SELECT @Mainsql AS max, @rowCount rowcnt

    IF @rowCount <> 0 BEGIN
        SELECT @sql += 'INSERT INTO #h ( sqltxt ) SELECT ''PRINT'''''' + ''[' + @db_name + ']''''''
        ' 
        SELECT @sql += 'INSERT INTO #h ( sqltxt ) SELECT ''USE '' + ''[' + @db_name + ']''
        ' 
        IF @db_name <>'tempdb' BEGIN 
            SELECT @sql += 'INSERT INTO #h ( sqltxt )
            SELECT ''ALTER DATABASE [' + @db_name + '] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;''
            '
        END 
        SELECT @sql += 'INSERT INTO #h ( sqltxt )
        SELECT ''ALTER DATABASE [' + @db_name + '] MODIFY FILEGROUP ['' + fg.name + ''] AUTOGROW_ALL_FILES''
        FROM [' + @db_name + '].sys.filegroups FG 
        WHERE FG.type <> ''FD''  /* no FILESTREAM_DATA_FILEGROUP */
        AND FG.type <> ''FX'' /* no MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA_FILEGROUP */
        AND FG.is_autogrow_all_files=0
        '

        IF @db_name <>'tempdb' BEGIN 
            SELECT @sql += 'INSERT INTO #h ( sqltxt )
            SELECT ''ALTER DATABASE [' + @db_name + '] SET MULTI_USER;''
            '
        END 
    END 
    --SELECT @sql 
    FETCH NEXT FROM dbcursor INTO @db_name
END

SELECT @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql

CLOSE dbcursor
DEALLOCATE dbcursor

SELECT @sql=''
SELECT @sql+=sqltxt + '
' FROM #h H 
ORDER BY i
SELECT @sql
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

It still has problems; if there are no files in a file group, I get an error message.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help.  Sometimes the execution will not be successful when in use by others.  You may either run it again or add a script to set the DB to single mode.

```
-- Run the results of this query, It will create queries for all databases in the server.

DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
SELECT @command = 'use [?]; SELECT ''ALTER DATABASE ? MODIFY FILEGROUP ['' + b.groupname + ''] AUTOGROW_ALL_FILES;'' 
FROM dbo.sysfiles a (NOLOCK)
JOIN dbo.sysfilegroups b (NOLOCK) ON a.groupid = b.groupid
GROUP BY b.groupname'

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

Comment: Note that `sp_MSforeachdb` is undocumented and unsupported by Micorosft. There is [a more reliable sp_MSforeachdb](https://sqlblog.org/2020/08/04/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb).